# Tuleap LDAP ERROR no:32

Tags: ldap, tuleap

Trying to configure Tuleap and LDAP authentication. So Far my config in /etc/tuleap/plugins/ldap/etc/ldap.inc:

```
$sys_ldap_server = 'xxx';
$sys_ldap_server_type = 'OpenLDAP';
$sys_ldap_dn = 'dc=xxx,dc=xx';
$sys_ldap_bind_dn = 'cn=useradmin,dc=xxx,dc=xx';
$sys_ldap_bind_passwd = 'xxxx';
$sys_ldap_uid = "uid";
$sys_ldap_eduid = "uid";
$sys_ldap_cn = 'cn';
$sys_ldap_mail = 'mail';
$sys_ldap_people_dn = 'ou=People,dc=xxx,dc=xx';
$sys_ldap_search_user='(|(uid=%words%)(cn=%words%)(mail=%words%))';
$sys_ldap_default_user_status = 'A';
$sys_ldap_svn_auth = 1;
$sys_ldap_daily_sync = 1;
$sys_ldap_daily_sync_retention_period = '';
$sys_ldap_user_management = 1;
$sys_ldap_grp_enabled = 1;
$sys_ldap_grp_dn = 'ou=workers,dc=xxx,dc=xx';
$sys_ldap_grp_cn = 'o';
$sys_ldap_grp_member = 'xxx';
$sys_ldap_threshold_users_suspension = '';
$search_depth = 'subtree';
```

When trying to login, I receive errors in log:

```
2018-08-14T09:05:56+02:00 [2247] [debug] Bound to LDAP server: xxx
2018-08-14T09:05:56+02:00 [2247] [warning] LDAP search error: dc=xxx,dc=xx uid=xxx@xxx.xx ldap://xxx.xx.xx ***ERROR:No such object ***ERROR no:32
2018-08-14T09:05:56+02:00 [2247] [info] [LDAP] User xxxx@xxx.xx failed to authenticate
```

Performing LDAP search in CLI brings up positive results:

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=useradmin,dc=xxx,dc=xx" -W -H ldap://xxx.xxx.xx -b "ou=People,dc=xxx,dc=xx"
```

Result:

```
# xxxx@xxx.xx, People, xxx.xx
dn: uid=xxxx@xxx.xx,ou=People,dc=xxx,dc=xx
cn:: www
displayName:: ppp
givenName: qq
mail: xxxx@xxx.xx
o: gg
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
preferredLanguage: cc
sn:: uuu
uid: xxxx@xxx.xx
userPassword:: yyy
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that Tuleap LDAP does not support login with email. Only with username. So, if your LDAP setup does not provide unique usernames you can't deploy LDAP login to Tuleap.

Comment: It seems I was wrong with my previous comment. Tuleap accepts email as username with LDAP. The problem is elsewhere, probably in 8 year old LDAP server :)